# show name from inner join with the id

Tags: php, arrays, oop, mysqli

i have this query :

```
select * from countrysegments 
   inner join country on countrysegments.country_id  = country.id
   inner join segments on countrysegments.segment_id = segments.id
```

all i need to know is how to show the name of the country inside table country,

and for each country show all the segments available,nothing worked with me, if someone could help me would me great,
thank u

i tried a lot with no answers,

i tried this:

`select * from countrysegments 
       inner join country on countrysegments.country_id  = country.country
       inner join segments on countrysegments.segment_id = segments.segment`

iknow im far from the correct answers but please can anyone help?

country_id is a foregin key of the id in country table
segment_id is a foreign key of the id in segments table

my database schema:

table name: countrysegments

```
id      country_id    segment_id
```

table name: country

```
id      country
```

table name: segments

```
id          segment
```

this is in class.php:`public function select(){
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT country FROM`country`") or die($this->conn->error);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                return $result;
            }
        }`

and this in index.php`

```
                            <th class="text-center">country</th>

                            <th class="text-center">segments</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

                require 'class.php';

                $conn = new db_class();
                $read = $conn->select();

                while($fetch = $read->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                                      foreach($fetch as $field=>$value){
   echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td>';
}


}       


            ?>




            </tbody>
        </table>`
```

with this solution i only have the query that show me the countries but i need to show in every country all the segments available using a dropdown menu

please i need your help all

Comment: show tables in DB

Comment: segments have:id  segment                                                                                             country have: id    country @BilalAhmed

Comment: show table structure. and sample output

Comment: show your table structure or create sql fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: post your database schema. It'll be easier that way

Comment: i already what tables are and what fields are but i couldn't find the solution to show the country inside country table and foreach country i want to show all segments in dropdown or select list @MahfuzurRahman

Comment: sorry eddy, but you'll need to give the whole context here. Your question is just showing SQL sentences and for your last comment, it seems you have an UI question actually. Please, rephrase the question so we can see what you want to accomplish at UI level.

Comment: ok i done it @MahfuzurRahman

Comment: BTW you should wrap the <th> tags with a <tr> tag in the <thead>.

Answer (score 1):

My version with some code. ;)

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">country</th>
        <th class="text-center">segments</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    require 'class.php';

    $conn = new db_class();
    $read = $conn->select(); // <-- here you'd call a query like this:
/*
"SELECT country.id AS countryID, country.country, segments.id AS segmentID, segments.segment
FROM countrysegments 
inner join country on countrysegments.country_id  = country.id
inner join segments on countrysegments.segment_id = segments.id
ORDER BY country.id, segments.id "
*/

// Then do some transformation for easier readability when creating the table!!
    $countryId = 0;
    $countries = [];
    while($fetch = $read->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if($countryId != $fetch['countryID']){
            $countryId = $fetch['countryID'];

            $countries[$countryId] = [
                'country' => $fetch['country'],
                'segments' => [],
            ];
        }

        $countries[$countryId]['segments'][] = [
            'segmentID' => $fetch['segmentID'],
            'segment' => $fetch['segment'],
        ];
    }

    // Here you can read the code to build the table easily ;)
    foreach($countries as $country){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$country['country']}</td>";
            echo "<td><select>";
            foreach($country['segments'] as $segment){
                echo "<option value=\"{$segment['segmentID']}\">{$segment['segment']}</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select country.id, country.country,segment.segment from countrysegments 
inner join country on countrysegments.country_id  = country.id
inner join segments on countrysegments.segment_id = segments.id where country.id = (any id of country).
```

it will give all segments of require country or you can remove `where` clause to get all segments of al countries and then you can play with results.